# how to trigger foreground/color of combobox text element to white?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

When IsMouseOver is true for my Toggle button, the Color of the arrow is White. I want the Text of the Combobox to have the same effect as the arrow when the Combobox IsEditible is false.

In this case, I need to modify the ComboBoxTemplate part. But I don't know how to implement it.

```
   <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Rectangle Margin="2" StrokeDashArray="1 2" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" StrokeThickness="1"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.Static.Background" Color="#1e1e1e"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.Static.Foreground" Color="#FF606060"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.MouseOver.Foreground" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
        <Style x:Key="ComboBoxEditableTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
            <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Background="Transparent" Foreground="{StaticResource TextBox.Static.Foreground}" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
                                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter  Property="Foreground"  Value="{StaticResource TextBox.MouseOver.Foreground  }"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
       
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Background" Color="#1e1e1e"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Foreground" Color="#FF606060"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Border" Color="#1e1e1e"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Glyph" Color="#FF606060"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Editable.Background" Color="#1e1e1e"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Editable.Border" Color="#1e1e1e"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Editable.Button.Background" Color="Transparent"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Editable.Button.Border" Color="Transparent"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Background" Color="#1e1e1e"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Border" Color="#1e1e1e"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Glyph" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Foreground" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Background" Color="#1e1e1e"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Border" Color="#1e1e1e"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Button.Background" Color="#1e1e1e"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Button.Border" Color="#1e1e1e"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Background" Color="#1e1e1e"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Border" Color="#1e1e1e"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Glyph" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Foreground" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Background" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Border" Color="#1e1e1e"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Button.Background" Color="#1e1e1e"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Button.Border" Color="#1e1e1e"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Background" Color="#1e1e1e"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Border" Color="#1e1e1e"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Glyph" Color="#FFBFBFBF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Foreground" Color="#FFBFBFBF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Background" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Border" Color="#FFBFBFBF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Button.Background" Color="Transparent"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Button.Border" Color="Transparent"/>
        <Style x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
            <Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Press"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                        <Border x:Name="templateRoot" Background="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Background}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Border}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <Border x:Name="splitBorder" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}">
                                <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="F1 M 0,0 L 2.667,2.66665 L 5.3334,0 L 5.3334,-1.78168 L 2.6667,0.88501 L0,-1.78168 L0,0 Z" Fill="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Glyph}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Editable.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Editable.Border}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Editable.Button.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Editable.Button.Border}"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Glyph}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="false"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Border}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Button.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Button.Border}"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Glyph}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="false"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Border}"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Border}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Button.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Button.Border}"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Glyph}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="false"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Border}"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Border}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Button.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Button.Border}"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxEditableTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" Width="0"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Placement="Bottom" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}">
                    <theme:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="shadow" Color="Transparent" MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=templateRoot}" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                        <Border x:Name="dropDownBorder" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}}" BorderThickness="1">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="DropDownScrollViewer">
                                <Grid x:Name="grid" RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                    <Canvas x:Name="canvas" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="opaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=dropDownBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=dropDownBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=dropDownBorder}"/>
                                    </Canvas>
                                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </theme:SystemDropShadowChrome>
                </Popup>
                <ToggleButton x:Name="toggleButton" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}"/>
                <Border x:Name="border" Background="{StaticResource TextBox.Static.Background}" BorderBrush="Red"   Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                             IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                             Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxEditableTextBox}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="border" Value="0.56"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" SourceName="PART_Popup" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="shadow" Value="0,0,5,5"/>
                    <Setter Property="Color" TargetName="shadow" Value="#71000000"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="dropDownBorder" Value="95"/>
                </Trigger>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="true"/>
                        <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" Value="false"/>
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                </MultiTrigger>
                <Trigger Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" SourceName="DropDownScrollViewer" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="opaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="opaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" Width="0"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="1" Placement="Bottom" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}">
                    <theme:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="shadow" Color="Transparent" MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=templateRoot}" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                        <Border x:Name="dropDownBorder" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}}" BorderThickness="1">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="DropDownScrollViewer">
                                <Grid x:Name="grid" RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                    <Canvas x:Name="canvas" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="opaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=dropDownBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=dropDownBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=dropDownBorder}"/>
                                    </Canvas>
                                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </theme:SystemDropShadowChrome>
                </Popup>
                <ToggleButton x:Name="toggleButton" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                              Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}"> </ToggleButton>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemStringFormat}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                                  Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                  IsHitTestVisible="false" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" SourceName="PART_Popup" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="shadow" Value="0,0,5,5"/>
                    <Setter Property="Color" TargetName="shadow" Value="#71000000"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="dropDownBorder" Value="95"/>
                </Trigger>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="true"/>
                        <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" Value="false"/>
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                </MultiTrigger>
                <Trigger Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" SourceName="DropDownScrollViewer" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="opaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="opaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
        <Style x:Key="ComboBoxStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Background}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground"  Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Foreground}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Border}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,3,5,3"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
            <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxTemplate}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxEditableTemplate}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ffffff" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox Style="{DynamicResource ComboBoxStyle1}"  x:Name="cmb1"  SelectionChanged="cmb1_SelectionChanged"   TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"  SnapsToDevicePixels="True" 
                   UseLayoutRounding="True"  RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor" RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled"   
                   Height="24.2" Width="246.5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock"  SnapsToDevicePixels="True" UseLayoutRounding="True" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"    Text="{Binding Name}"
                               TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" ></TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

codebehind:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            List<AudioDevice> devices = new List<AudioDevice>();
            devices.Add(new AudioDevice() { Name = "Audio1", Direction = "direction1" });
            devices.Add(new AudioDevice() { Name = "Audio2", Direction = "direction1" });
            devices.Add(new AudioDevice() { Name = "Audio3", Direction = "direction2" });
            ListCollectionView lcv = new ListCollectionView(devices);
            lcv.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Direction"));
            this.cmb1.ItemsSource = lcv;
            DataContext = this;
        }
        private int _selected;
        public int Selected
        {
            get
            {
                return _selected;
            }
            set
            {
                _selected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Selected");
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        internal void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
        private void cmb1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            cmb1.Foreground = (SolidColorBrush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#939393");
        }
    }
    public class AudioDevice
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Direction { get; set; }
        public override string ToString() { return Name; }
    }
```

The result:

[image]
update:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `ContentPresenter` inside the ComboBox-Template to a `ContentControl` and add an `IsMouseOver` trigger that changes the foreground of the ContentControl:

```
           <!-- ... other parts of the control template removed for readability ... -->
            <ToggleButton x:Name="toggleButton"
                          Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                          BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                          BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                          IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen,
                                              Mode=TwoWay,
                                              RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                          Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" />
            <ContentControl x:Name="contentPresenter"
                            Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                            Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                            ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemStringFormat}"
                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                            ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                            IsHitTestVisible="false"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Setter TargetName="contentPresenter"
                        Property="Foreground"
                        Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Glyph}" />
            </Trigger>

            <!-- other triggers... -->

        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Update: This way the foreground color does not change back once you open the popup and move the mover over an item. This is a different behavior from the arrow.

To have the same behavior as the arrow, you can do the following:

1. Bind the `Foreground` property of the `ContentControl` to the `Foreground` of the `ToggleButton` using an element binding.
2. Change the `Trigger` in the ToggleButtonStyle to change the `Foreground` property of the ToggleButton instead of the `Fill` of the arrow shape.
3. Bind the `Fill` property of the arrow shape to the `Foreground` of the ToggleButton.

Here is the updated Control Template:

```
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTemplate"
                     TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Grid x:Name="templateRoot"
              SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0"
                                  MinWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup">
                <!-- removed for readability -->
            </Popup>
            <ToggleButton x:Name="toggleButton"
                          Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                          BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                          BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                          IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen,
                                              Mode=TwoWay,
                                              RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                          Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" />
            <ContentControl x:Name="contentPresenter"
                            Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                            Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                            ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemStringFormat}"
                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                            ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                            Foreground="{Binding Path=Foreground,
                                                 ElementName=toggleButton}"
                            IsHitTestVisible="false"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger SourceName="PART_Popup" Property="HasDropShadow" Value="true">
                <Setter TargetName="shadow" Property="Margin" Value="0,0,5,5" />
                <Setter TargetName="shadow" Property="Color" Value="#71000000" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                <Setter TargetName="dropDownBorder" Property="Height" Value="95" />
            </Trigger>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="true" />
                    <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" Value="false" />
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false" />
            </MultiTrigger>
            <Trigger SourceName="DropDownScrollViewer" Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false">
                <Setter TargetName="opaqueRect" Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}" />
                <Setter TargetName="opaqueRect" Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}" />
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

And the ComboBoxToggleButton-Style:

```
        <Style x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton"
           TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false" />
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false" />
        <Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Press" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Border x:Name="templateRoot"
                            Background="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Border}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Border x:Name="splitBorder"
                                Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}"
                                Margin="0"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                BorderBrush="Transparent"
                                BorderThickness="1"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <Path x:Name="arrow"
                                  Margin="0"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                  Data="F1 M 0,0 L 2.667,2.66665 L 5.3334,0 L 5.3334,-1.78168 L 2.6667,0.88501 L0,-1.78168 L0,0 Z"
                                  Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
                        </Border>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <!-- other triggers removed for readability -->
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Glyph}" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                    <Setter TargetName="contentPresenter"  Property="TextElement.Foreground"
                        Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Glyph}" />
                </Trigger>

I modified the code as follows, but IsMouseOver is false, the Foreground is still white, and it does not have the same effect as the arrow.

Comment: <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="contentPresenter"  Property="TextElement.Foreground"
                            Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Glyph}" />
                    </Trigger>
     <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="contentPresenter"  Property="TextElement.Foreground"
                            Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Glyph}" />
                    </Trigger>

Comment: This is because the mouse is still over the ComboBox-Template when you hover over the popup. I updated my answer with a solution that addresses this issue.

Comment: Hi, @Tobias Hoefer. I tested your updated code without success, did it work when you tested it?

Comment: Yes i tested it and it worked for me. Have you made any other changes to the template or  style?